# How to NetworkManager, resolvconf, and dsnmasq work together?

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns, dnsmasq, resolvconf

Running Kubuntu 16.04

Sometimes the name resolution gets slow. In previous Ubuntu versions, the problem was usually in resolv.conf and was easy to fix. In 16.04 all the DNS resolution is hidden in a NetworkManager+resolvconf+dsnmasq maze, and I don't know how I can figure out the actual DNS (`dig` says it's 127.0.1.1).

Could a kind soul explain:

1. how NetworkManager, resolvconf, and dsnmasq work together (because this is something that is not explained in the documentation of each)
2. how can I debug DNS performance problems

#### Additional information

```
ls -al /etc/resolv.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Apr  8  2017 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
```

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

```
dpkg -l *dnsmasq*
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
un  dnsmasq        <none>       <none>       (no description available)
ii  dnsmasq-base   2.75-1ubuntu amd64        Small caching DNS proxy and DHCP/
```

```
host -v www.ebay.com                                     
Trying "www.ebay.com"                                                     
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 46563                 
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0      

;; QUESTION SECTION:                                                      
;www.ebay.com.                  IN      A                                 

;; ANSWER SECTION:                                                        
www.ebay.com.           292     IN      CNAME   slot9428.ebay.com.edgekey.net.                                                                      
slot9428.ebay.com.edgekey.net. 10094 IN CNAME   e9428.b.akamaiedge.net.   
e9428.b.akamaiedge.net. 12      IN      A       104.80.20.236             

Received 122 bytes from 127.0.1.1#53 in 2 ms                              
Trying "e9428.b.akamaiedge.net"
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 35831
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;e9428.b.akamaiedge.net.                IN      AAAA

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
b.akamaiedge.net.       674     IN      SOA     n0b.akamaiedge.net. hostmaster.akamai.com. 1564414527 1000 1000 1000 1800

Received 101 bytes from 127.0.1.1#53 in 2 ms
Trying "e9428.b.akamaiedge.net"
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 16147
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;e9428.b.akamaiedge.net.                IN      MX

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
b.akamaiedge.net.       992     IN      SOA     n0b.akamaiedge.net. hostmaster.akamai.com. 1564414845 1000 1000 1000 1800

Received 101 bytes from 127.0.1.1#53 in 2 ms
```

```
cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

```
cat /etc/hosts | head
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   Xenoid

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

```
cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

```
cat /etc/nsswitch.conf 
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         compat
group:          compat
shadow:         compat
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` and `cat /etc/resolv.conf` and `dpkg -l *dnsmasq*`. How do you know it's a DNS resolution problem that's causing the slowness?

Comment: @heynnema Done. DNS suspected because page loads/downloads are fast (I'm on fiber), but slow to start. Other clues, my PC connects to several different networks during the day (home, customer, phone hotspot, VPN...). A reboot seems to fix things for a while (which I did last night and which is why I am asking for debugging hints to investigate myself when thing get slow again).

Comment: It's been so long since I've worked on a 16.04 problem :-) I can't remember if it uses systemd yet. Lets try some simple commands... `resolvectl` may not work. `host -v www.ebay.com` run this twice... look at the last line of output... notice the DNS server IP and the time in ms. The first time value should be, say, 60ms, but the second time should be around 0ms. Report back.

Comment: Also show me `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/hosts` (first 5 lines only) and `cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`.

Comment: And `cat /etc/nsswitch.conf`.

Comment: The `host -v www.ebay.com` results are 2ms for both times, meaning that you've used www.ebay.com since the machine was booted. Try the `host` command with a site name that you haven't used... like `www.ibm.com`, or some such. Compare the times between the first run and the second. Also, start comments to me with @heynnema or when you update your question, or I'll surely miss the changes.

Comment: @heynnema I tried on www.whitehouse.gov (I checked a couple of IBM pages today) and same results. The problem is that all these sites are behind a CDN. Also, as stated in the question, rebooting did fix the problem, so I just want to know how I can investigate it next time. Anything besides the `host -v`?

Comment: What I was trying to prove/disprove was if dnsmasq was working. If you're getting 2ms response times, then right now anyway, dns isn't your problem. Try the `host -v` commands later when things seem to slow down. All the rest of the data we covered looks fine. Are you using a VPN? What is CDN?

Comment: @heynnema CDN: [content delivery network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network): akamai, cloudflare and such. They do play tricks with DNS. No VPN, plain FTTH when at home.

Comment: Please keep me posted if things slow down again. Cheers!